# How to load Couchbase Memcached buckets

Tags: java, memcached, couchbase, spymemcached

Does the Java client API support loading Memcached buckets in Couchbase or only Couchbase buckets are supported and if so what is the best way of using Memcached buckets on Couchbase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this functionality was broken in CouchbaseClient 1.1.3 though.

The client should figure out what kind of bucket your using and do the right thing so you shouldn't be having problems unless your using the client mentioned above.

[Latest version 1.1.4](http://packages.couchbase.com/clients/java/1.1.4/Couchbase-Java-Client-1.1.4.zip), or through the [Couchbase maven repo](http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/couchbase/couchbase-client/1.1.4/)

Comment: I suppose you meant version 1.1.3 instead of 1.3. And yes I am using this version. But it appears that, this issue has been fixed in version 1.1.4. Here's the release notes for the latest Java client version.http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-sdk-java-1.1/couchbase-sdk-java-rn_1-1-4a.html

Comment: Also, this was broken in 1.1.3 by accident and then fixed so if you have 1.1.1 or 1.1.2 this should work correctly.

Comment: Yes. I finally realised that. If you include the link to the latest version (1.1.4) in your answer as an edit I will mark it as answer.